# Rails: Can I reference a table directly and via a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

In my app I track various tasks.  Each task has a person_id referencing a persons table.  The persons table references the companies table.  This way I can see for each task who is responsible for the task and what company they belong to.

My models are as follows:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  delegate :workspace, :to => :project, :allow_nil => true
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :importance
  belongs_to :urgency
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :tasks
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :people
end
```

I want to be able to add a reference to my tasks table which allows me to monitor which client the specific task is.  I could create a new table called client and populate it with all the client names.  However, as I already have the companies table, this seems to be duplicating data.  As such, is there a way of me having the client_id reference in the tasks table as well as the person_id?  I am concerned that this will cause issues especially in my controllers when I run a query on some data as each task will belong to a client and also have a person responsible for the task which most likely would belong to a different company.

Answer (score 0):

first option, you create client table and do the relationship as follow,

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  delegate :workspace, :to => :project, :allow_nil => true
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :importance
  belongs_to :urgency
end


class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :clients , :through => :tasks
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :people , :through => :tasks
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :people
  has_many :clients
end
```

- task.client.company = this will generate query with client_id
- task.person.company = this will generate query with person_id

second option, which I think more advance solution using many to many self join
you just need to add client_id to task and do not need to create client table since its going to use person table

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, foreign_key: "client_id", class_name: "Person"
  belongs_to :person, foreign_key: "person_id", class_name: "Person"
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  # as person
    has_many: client_relations, foreign_key: :person_id, class_name: "Task"
    has_many: clients, through: :client_relations, source: :client
  # as client
    has_many: person_relations, foreign_key: :client_id, class_name: "Task"
    has_many: people, through: :person_relations, source: :person
end
```